# Make a copy of object

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uibutton

I have a UIScrollView on it I have `UIImageView`'s and `UIButton`, when I create temp `UIScrollView` and try to do something like this:

```
for (UIView *viewCopy in scrollView.subviews) 
{
       [tempScrollView addSubview:viewCopy];
}
```

Pointer of each subview on scrollView disappearing. I need make a copy of each object? How to make a copy of `UIImageView` and `UIButton`? Thanks..

Comment: What is the tempScrollView for? Is it still a valid object by the time you use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIImageView` and UIButton, being derived from `UIView`, do not conform to the `NSCopying` protocol. So, you cannot make a copy.

You can instantiate multiple time `UIImageView` and `UIButton` and have as many objects as you need.

In any case, it is not clear what you mean by: "Pointer of each subview on scrollView disappearing"

Comment: I mean that when I doing this `[tempScrollView addSubview:viewCopy];`, main scrollView don't contains this object, now this object on tempScrollView, am I right?

Comment: I understand.. but how to do it?

Comment: In the same way as you created them in the first place: `[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:...];`

Comment: oh.. so I can't make a copy of UIImageView.. can I copy a UIScrollView with all content and properties?

Comment: @sergio Why do you say "I would call `removeFromSuperview` before calling `addSubview`... otherwise you could have problems."? The `addSubview:` [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addSubview:) says: "Views can have only one superview. If view already has a superview and that view is not the receiver, this method removes the previous superview before making the receiver its new superview."